# Core Service Keyword Creation

Tags: core-service

I am creating keywords using the core service with the below code, the problem is I don't want to use a hardcoded TCM ID for the `Category`, as this may change between environments.

Is there any way to avoid this, as it appears you can't get a `webdav` path for Categories?

```
CategoryData category = (CategoryData)_coreService.Read("tcm:344-10060-512",  defaultReadOptions);

KeywordData keyword = (KeywordData)_coreService.GetDefaultData(ItemType.Keyword, category.Id);
keyword.Id = "tcm:0-0-0";
keyword.Title = value;
keyword.Key = key;

keyword = (KeywordData)_coreService.Create(keyword, _defaultReadOptions);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After running some test, it appears you can pass in a WebDav path to the Category, although the webdav path is in no means intuitive, it takes the format, /webdav/**publication name/category name/**

```
CategoryData category = (CategoryData)_coreService.Read("/webdav/publication name/category name/",  defaultReadOptions);
```

thanks Ibrar Hussain for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Glad to have been proven wrong :) I've done this with Folder creation, didn't think it was possible with Taxonomy!

Answer (score 7):

Just a little note on this one. If you wish to target the keywords themselves and not the category you will need to use the .tkw extension. The categories do not use any extension as shown in Pete's example. So for example (../20Parent%20Publication/Places/My%20Keyword.tkw). A good little trick to figure out some of these none intuitive extensions is to request the WebDavUrl based on the tcm id of the thing you are trying to get the path to. So in this case get the id of the categories and request the WebDavUrl.