# How to add/insert a keyword into a component field using Core Service?

Tags: core-service, sdl-tridion

I need to add a Keyword based on its Keyword title using the Core Service. Please help me which function of Core Service I can use along with some sample code if possible as well.

I have a Keyword field name called "familyKeyword" Here I just need to insert a Keyword to field name family keyword using Core Service.

[image]

string domainName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["domainName"];

```
        string userName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["userName"];

        string passowrd = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["passowrd"];
        timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd:MM:yy h:mm:ss tt").Replace(":", "_").Replace(" ", "");

        string content = string.Empty;
        //string familyKeyword = "familyKeyword";
        //string keywordTitle = "Aromatics & Fibers";

        client = CoreServiceClientFactory.GetClient();

        var ComponentContent = client.Read("tcm:13-149625", new ReadOptions()) as ComponentData;
        content = ComponentContent.Content;
```

Comment: Welcome to Tridion Stackexchange!

This link could help you: 
https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1352/core-service-keyword-creation

Comment: Duplicate of: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/20752/how-to-add-a-keyword-in-tridion-using-core-service

Comment: @AtilaSos - I don't think that this is a duplicate. The answer you point to is about creating a new keyword within a category. However, this question seems to be about updating a field within a component to be a specific keyword.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is to have the component `tcm:13-149625` updated. Since you want the keyword ***Aromatics & Fibers*** inserted into the ***familyKeyword*** field, you would have to first read the keyword and update the component by inserting a new node which would insert the keyword title to the field.

```
// Parse the component's content into an XML.
var contentXml = XElement.Parse(component.Content);

// Read the "Aromatics & Fibers" keyword.
KeywordData keywordData = (KeywordData)client.Read("tcm:xx-xxx-1024", null);

// Create a new node for the "familyKeyword" field. 
XNamespace ns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
XElement familyKeywordNode = new XElement(contentXml.GetDefaultNamespace() + "familyKeyword", 
    new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xlink", ns),
    new XAttribute(ns + "href", keywordData.Id),
    new XAttribute(ns + "title", keywordData.Title));
familyKeywordNode.Value = keywordData.Title;

// Add the  "familyKeyword" field into the content.
contentXml.Add(familyKeywordNode);

// Update the component.
component.Content = contentXml.ToString();
client.Update(component, null);
```

This stack exchange question [How to update the component particular field node using core service](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11597/how-to-update-the-component-particular-field-node-using-core-service) about how to update components should also help you. Hope this helps!

Comment: the keyword is getting insert at the last in the source .i need to add the familykeyword in between two fields say "x Field" + family Keyword Field +"yField"

Comment: This is just XML manipulation. You'd have to grab the node you want to insert after. Here in your case x Field and use `AddAfterSelf` on this object to insert the familykeyword.

Comment: can i get a sample code? I tried it was not working for me. Sample code is much appreciated. thanks!!

Comment: This should help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972412/insert-xelements-after-a-specific-node. Here a node is inserted after a specific node. Note: in your case, there are namespaces and you should factor that in too.